# Generating Single photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics

How can single photons be generated by making a coherent state weaker by attenuating it?(For reference please see, **Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang**, *10th edition,pg.288.*)

Comment: You are always generating "single" photons (even when you are making pairs). The only difference is the photon density and/or average photon flux. A fast detector can distinguish single photons at a higher flux than a slow detector can.

Comment: search for Alain Aspect and single photons

Comment: @Subhadip: Please see my answer to a related question by you: 
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239455/spdc-and-single-photon-production/239739#239739